# What is best way to learn maybe any guide/tutorial for selenium in ruby?

Tags: ruby, selenium, selenium-ide

I want to learn to write selenium script in ruby but I am new to ruby, could you suggest any material to get started.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of Selenium look at https://github.com/jnicklas/capybara

'Capybara aims to simplify the process of integration testing Rack applications, such as Rails, Sinatra or Merb. Capybara simulates how a real user would interact with a web application. It is agnostic about the driver running your tests and currently comes with Rack::Test and Selenium support built in.'